# DataWriter/DataReader Relation

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm a bit confused on how these two affect each other after reading the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.

If I were to DetachStream and Dispose on the writer, does the reader end up being null? I am seeing this flagged in a codebase quality checker.

```
writer = new DataWriter(_device.OutputStream);
writer.WriteString(command);
await writer.StoreAsync();
writer.DetachStream();

reader = new DataReader(_device.InputStream);
IAsyncOperation<uint> taskLoad = reader.LoadAsync(10000);
taskLoad.AsTask().Wait();

var bytesToRead = taskLoad.GetResults();
var response = reader.ReadString(bytesToRead);

reader.DetachStream();
reader = null;
```

Exception handling..

```
if (writer != null) {
    writer.DetachStream();
    writer.Dispose();
}

if (reader != null) {
    reader.DetachStream();
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Apparently reader is always null in this case?

Comment: the writer and reader should be 2 different objects. can I see where you define the writer and the reader?

Comment: Updated post, the whole thing is surrounded by try/catch and I am disposing in a finally block.

Comment: Unless you know the text you're reading is exactly one byte per character (eg, it's pure ASCII) your code will crash. Bytes read != codeunits to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are doing is dispose the reader, and set it to null.

After doing so you do the same in the finally block.
the finally block will always run, even if the try fails and comes into the catch block.
So there is no need to have

```
reader.DetachStream();
reader = null;
```

In your try block.
just remove it from the try block and your codebase quality checker will stop complaining.